# How to code this header design?

Tags: html, css

[image: The header I'm talking about]

I recently received this design from a potential client, and although we didn't agree to work together I was going to attempt to code the design for some practice. This is not my design (and I'm not claiming it is), and I am not intending on using it for anything, purely for practice. This is also why I blocked out the name of the company.

Anyways, I'm pretty stumped when it comes to this header/navigation area. The decorations to the side of the logo, and the logo essentially spanning two divs, really throw me off. I was wondering how any of you would go about coding this.

I was thinking just a div for each side decoration, and then the logo would have to be absolutely positioned. Is this a correct solution?

I first even tried incorporating it into the 960grid system, but that was going nowhere because the logo spanning problem made the grid very difficult.

Comment: Your question is too broad, but the big picture is: Remove all the menu items and make everything else a single image. Add it as the background of a div with `position: relative`, and position the menu ul with `position: absolute`. The menu items can be done with `font-face`, CSS sprites, or individual images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen if the client BOUGHT the font, you could always font-face the font which would make it easier for you.

Other than that, I would remove the dots between the links and the text and use the image for the background, then just create one UL giving each li a class for the page ie home, about, galleries then use some PHP to add current_page class.

Then after galleries create another li with the following markup:

```
<li class="logo"><a href="/">Logo</a></li>
```

Add style like so.

```
li.logo {
    background: transparent url(....) no-repeat;
    width: width of logo;
    height: height of logo;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li.logo a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you'd like me to do it for you, or show you examples I'd be happy to.

Comment: If you're willing to do it or give more specific examples, that would be great. I see how you plan on doing the navigation/logo, but then how would the logo overlap into the darker background, and how would you do the two images on either side of the logo? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your talking about, I don;t see any logo or two images on either side?

Comment: Hopefully I can be more descriptive and make sense...

The "logo" I'm referring to is the emblem-shaped object in the center, with the blocked out company name. It is in the middle of the navigation, and overlaps between the dark background up top, and the unordered list.

The "two images on the side" are the curly decorations on each side of the logo, up in the darker background. 

Hopefully that makes more sense. One solution that comes to mind would be just to make the whole thing the background-image of the header, and only worry about the navigation/logo coding?

Comment: Is this a PSD file, but yes that is what I said, you need to make everything a background image excluding the navigation text, li separators, and the logo.

Comment: OR you could leave the logo in there and just make a non-text based link, designers do it all the  time, I never link a logo directly by IMG, it just makes it easier for the logo to be distributed and targeted by search engines.

Comment: I understand what you're going for now, thank you for explaining more and sorry for my vague wording. Definitely a good approach and possibly the way I'd do it, I'll have to try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use one list and add a class on the 3rd item to give it a big enough `margin-right` to create space for a `h1` logo. This way your markup is nice and semantic and you don't have to use multiple `div`'s and lists.

You could also use the `nth-child` CSS selector instead of adding a class.

Comment: How would you guarantee the logo is placed in the center of the nav?

Comment: I'd assume the first 3 nav items are not going to change.

Answer (score 1):

I'd break the design into 2 rows, like so:

[image]

The "design" bits can sit on either side of the logo image in the center of the fist row.  This lets you link the logo but not the designs.  The second row gets sliced up for the navigation elements and the logo.  I'd put it all inside a div with a set width and height that is the exact dimensions of all the various images.  Keep it simple.  You can put the rows into individual divs, but I think you'd be fine without it.

For a super low-budget implementation, use the image as-is and apply an image map to it to add the links you need.  You lose options like rollover images, but that's what makes it low budget.

Since this is a learnng exercise, try coding it up several different ways.  Float all the elements, position them absolutely, make columns, make rows, use a big background image and and position the navigation over it, and anything else you can think of - but no tables!  :)

Comment: Of course no tables! Thank you for the ideas, I'll try some of them soon to see what I can get to work.

Comment: I'd vote for "use a big background image and and position the navigation over it". Fewer server hits == better performance (although you could create a single sprite image containing several smaller images which would have the same result).